# getting run time error in online judge for codevita

Tags: java

Below is the question
the main problem is to get the total number of inversions

```
Count Bits
Problem Description
Given a sequence of distinct numbers a1, a2, ….. an, an inversion occurs if there are indices i<j such that ai > aj .

For example, in the sequence 2 1 4 3 there are 2 inversions (2 1) and (4 3).

The input will be a main sequence of N positive integers. From this sequence, a Derived derived sequence will be obtained using the following rule. The output is the number of inversions in the derived sequence.

Rule for forming derived sequence

The derived sequence is formed by counting the number of 1s bits in the binary representation of the corresponding number in the input sequence.

Thus, if the input is 3,4,8, the binary representation of the numbers are 11,100 and 1000. The derived sequence is the number of 1sin the binary representation of the numbers in the input sequence, and is 2,1,1

Constraints
N <= 50

Integers in sequence <= 107

Input Format
The first line of the input will have a single integer, which will give N.

The next line will consist of a comma separated string of N integers, which is the main sequence

Output
The number of inversions in the derived sequence formed from the main sequence.


Explanation
Example 1

Input

5

55, 53, 88, 27, 33

Output

8

Explanation

The number of integers is 5, as specified in the first line. The given sequence is 55, 53, 88, 27, 33.

The binary representation is 110111, 110101, 1011000, 11011, 100001and 100001 . The derived sequence is 5,4,3,4,2, 4,3,4,2 (corresponding to the number of 1s bits). The number of inversions in this is 8, namely (5,4),(5,3),(5,4),(5,2),(4,3),(4,2),(3,2),(4,2). Hence the output is 8.

Example 2

Input

8

120,21,47,64,72,35,18,98

Output

15

Explanation

The number of integers is 8. The given sequence is 120,21,47,64,72,35,18,98. The corresponding binary sequence is 1111000,10101,101111,1000000,1001000,100011, 10010,1100010. The derived sequence (number of 1s) is 4,3,5,1,2,3,2,3. The number of inversions is 15, namely (4,3),(4,1),(4,2),(4,3),(4,2),(4,3),(3,1),(3,2),(3,2),(5,1),(5,2),(5,3), (5,2), (5,3),(3,2). Hence the output is 15.
```

this is my solution

```
    package SudoPlacement;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Inversion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String line = null;
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        line = sc.next();
        String[] parts = line.split(",");
        int[] arr = new int[n];
        for (int i=0;i<parts.length;i++)
            arr[i]=Integer.parseInt(parts[i]);
        int[] countArray = new int[n];
        for (int i=0;i<n;i++){

            int value=0;
            while (arr[i]!=0) {
                value+= arr[i]%2;
                arr[i]=arr[i]/2;
            }
            countArray[i]=value;
        }

        int noOfInversions = 0;
        for (int i=0;i<countArray.length;i++) {
            for (int j=0;j<countArray.length;j++){
                if (countArray[i]>countArray[j] && i<j)
                    noOfInversions++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(noOfInversions);
    }


}
```

While using local ide(Intellij), I am getting the correct output as required but when I try to submit the code, I am getting runtime error.
Can anyone help me on this one?

This is the only thing online ide is showing for runtime error

[image]

This is output in my ide
[image]

Comment: what is the runtime error?

Comment: Do you get a runtime error? Which one? Or is the result a failure for taking too much time for running?

Comment: Please provide textual information in textual shape (i.e. not as a picture of text), in order to keep users here in a helpful mood.

Comment: @Yunnosch if i try to add the textual information it might take a lot of text which stackoverflow might not allow

Comment: "might"? Did you try?

Comment: @Yunnosch sorry I thought it might throw an error. Now I have posted the textual question, Now can you help ?

Comment: @hsnsd i have added the output from my ide

Comment: I will try. Meanwhile have a look here https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try commenting out this line     `package SudoPlacement;`
 from your solution. I have made this mistake several times and got the same run time errors while uploading solutions to online judges.